# How can I modify a Vue Loader setting in Laravel Mix?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, vue-loader, vue-apollo

Using Laravel Mix by the way... and trying to use Vue Apollo, it says we need to add this to babel config:

```
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        transpileOptions: {
                            transforms: {
                                dangerousTaggedTemplateString: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

but that is giving me `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.` error that I haven't been able to find a solution for, except for a thread somewhere in Google saying it's because I'm using `vue-loader` twice..

So, what I'm trying to do now that may fix this error is to apply that `dangerousTaggedTemplateString` setting to the existing webpack configuration for .vue files.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Are you using Vue-CLI or raw webpack?  Are you using vue-cli-plugin-apollo?  Where do you see that you're supposed to edit babel's config?  [This](https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/components/query.html#tag-setup) says vue.config.js, and then only if you're not using vue-cli-plugin-apollo

Comment: Not using vue-cli at all, and that link you point to says also that when you're not using vue-cli that you should edit raw webpack config. I'm editing webpack.mix.js, initially it looked like this: mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested), leave the `mix.js` line you mentioned untouched.
Then on a new line:

```
mix.options({
   vue: {
      transpileOptions: {
         transforms: {
            dangerousTaggedTemplateString: true
         }
      }
   }
});
```